# Sample OpenCV Neural Network codes

Tags: c, ubuntu, opencv, neural-network

I am new to using OpenCV for neural netowrks.Can you please provide me with any sample codes or links for beginners from where I can read and get a sense of coding ANN with openCV.I am working in Ubuntu.

Comment: I assume you're using OpenCV to grab images and apply some transform on it based on what the neural network determines? In that case, general neural network tutorials will be a good start. Try googling.

Comment: Well I have the basic idea and knowledge of neural networks.I just dont know how to use them with OpenCV

Answer (score 3):

I know it has been years since that question was asked. But I wanted to share this great tutorial of Machine learning with OpenCV:

http://www.bytefish.de/pdf/machinelearning.pdf
http://bytefish.de/blog/machine_learning_opencv/

Answer (score 0):

- [Autonomous Ground Vehicle](http://projectagv.blogspot.com/)